# Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

I have a simple code in MATLAB which I am trying to translate to python, but I am stuck in a simple for loop:
Here is the situation:
Matlab

```
f0 = constant
fn = (nx1) matrix
b = (nx1) matrix
d and x are constant
mthd = 1 or 2

s = 1:-0.1:0.1;
for i = 1:10
  f = fn * s(i)
    switch mthd
    case 1
       v(:,i) = d *(1 + 1./b.*(f0./f)).^x
    case 2
       v(:,i) = log(f0./f)./b;
       v(:,i) = v./(1+v)
    end
    v(1,:) = min(vp(2,:));
```

The output in Matlab results v with nx1 matrix

Assuming it is a simple equation with element wise operation in matlab, 
I went ahead and wrote a code in python like this:

```
s = np.linspace(1,0.1,num=10)
for i in range(1,11)
   f = fn * s[i]
   if mthd ==1:
       v = d *(1 + 1/b*(f0/f))^x
   elif mthd ==2: 
       v = log(f0/f)/b;
       v = v/(1+v)
```

Clearly, this is not the right one and I get stuck right from f = fn* s[i]
Any suggestion in this conversion will be of great help.
Thank you

Comment: Without going into details for sentence is missing : `for i in range(1,11):`

Comment: Remember that ^ stands for bitwise XOR operations instead of exponentiation, you must use ** instead

Comment: The title explains your problem very well, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly this is not the right one and I get stuck right from f = fn* s[i]

What error message are you getting here? Make sure your vectors `fn` and `b` are numpy arrays and not lists.

> `for i in range(1,11)`

Python uses zero indexing, whereas Matlab uses 1-indexing. Therefore your for loop should use `for i in range(10)`, which iterates from 0 to 9 instead of 1 to 10.

> `v = d *(1 + 1/b*(f0/f))^x`

Assuming fn and b are numpy arrays in your Python implementation, if you really want this to mirror the Matlab code you can still use indexing such as `v[:,i]`. However you need to initialize `v` as a numpy array with the correct size first.

> `v = log(f0/f)/b;`

You probably want np.log here.

Hopefully this is helpful, let me know if you still have questions. You may also find [this website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The code block below should be closer to what you want. Here are a few things to look out for:

1. Phyton arrays are indexed from 0. In base Python you handle powers with `**` e.g. `2 ** 2` equals `4`
2. When performing scalar multiplication and divide of arrays, better to use `np.multiply` and `np.divide`
3. Use `np.log` for logarithm and `np.power` for exponentiation with `numpy` matrices.
4. Use `np.add` to add a scalar to a `numpy` array.

---

```
import numpy as np

f0 = 5 # constant 
fn = np.matrix([[5], [4], [3], [2], [1]]) # 5 x 1 matrix 
b = np.matrix([[9], [8], [7], [6], [5]]) # 5 x 1 matrix 

# d and x are constant
d = 4
x = 8

# mthd = 1 or 2
mthd = 1

s = np.linspace(1,0.1,num=10)

# python arrays are indexed from 0
for i in range(0,len(s)):
   f = fn * s[i]

   if mthd == 1:
       v = np.power(np.multiply(d, (1 + np.divide(1., np.multiply
                                              (b, np.divide(f0, f) ) ) ) ), x)
   elif mthd ==2: 
        v = np.divide(np.log(np.divide(f0,f)), b);
        v = np.divide(v, (np.add(1, v)) )
```